# Please explain what this Syncsort code does?

Tags: sorting, jcl, syncsort

The below code was in a proc which is included in my job under the DD name `sort.controls`. 
This step was executed with the sort program, Syncsort. I can understand that the `START` in the below code indicates the starting position of the field used for sorting and `LENGTH` denotes the length of the field for sorting. But I can't understand what is  `ID TYPECODE=1`. Can anyone please explain this?

```
ID TYPECODE=1,LRECL=00302,FORMAT=FB 
CF1 START=00038,LENGTH=023
```

Comment: I don't have current Syncsort doc available, and my old doc doesn't have this syntax, so I'm making a guess. Is it a reference point to the CF1, that is, the number following the CF ties that particular statement back to the ID statement with that TYPECODE?

Comment: Thes are not SyncSort Control Statements. Internet searches on the keywords only lead back to variations of this same question. Best guess is that SORT.CONTROLS is a DD name for a user-written SORT EXIT to allow a generalised program to process fixed-length records of different lengths (for variable-length records, the length is provided to the EXIT). No-one not working at that specific site will benefit from this question are any answers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an unknown program at the user's site.

Answer (score 2):

`ID Type code 1` is system-specific. In my experience it normally means it's a disk file vs a cart or carddata or something but I'd have to know more about your environment.

`LRECL` is the defined length of the record for that file (302 bytes)

`Format=FB` means it is Fixed Block - the length is always 302 bytes and does not vary.

Hopefully that's helpful.